# Tail log and output top processes upon encountering string fails

Tags: command-line, find, awk, top, tail

I am running the following command to tail a log file and output top processes to a file upon encountering a given string:

```
tail -f mylogfile.log | awk '
                /server on fire/ { system("/bin/sh -c 'if [ -n `find snapshot.txt -mmin +30` ]; then top -n 1 -b | tee -a snapshot.txt; fi'") }'
```

This command fails with a syntax error (probably because some of the characters should be escaped) & I can't get it to work.  Please help

Note: the find command checks if at least 30 minutes have passed since last write to file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I believe I finally got it to work:

```
tail -f mylogfile.log | awk '
                /server on fire/ { if (system("[ ! -f snapshot.txt ]") == 0 || system("find snapshot.txt -mmin +30 | grep -q .") == 0) system("top -n 1 -b >> snapshot.txt") }' &
```